# File redirect using HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on a website and stuck at one thing

i want if a.html exists then open a.html
else open a.php, I am really bad in htaccess an all.. please help me guys.Please

insted of this example.com/foo i want if someone type example.com/foo.html then it will check for foo.html if it does not exists then redirect to foo.html now whats happening if user will type foo.html then page is showing 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to load a URL like: `http://example.com/foo` and if `foo.html` exists, then return the content of that file, otherwise check if `foo.php` exists, then return the contents of that file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L]
```

Alternatively, you could just turn on multiviews. It's sort of what mod_negotiation is made for:

```
Options Multiviews
```

Comment: insted of this http://example.com/foo
i want if someone type http://example.com/foo.html then it will check for foo.html if it does not exists then redirect to foo.html

now whats happening if user will type foo.html then page is showing 404 not found

Comment: So you want to check for **foo.html** and if it doesn't exist, *redirect the browser to* **foo.html**? If it doesn't exist, of course you'll get a 404